# Why won't these anchor links work?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I have the anchor links working fine in the navigation (Services -> Headhunting/Executive Search etc)
But the anchor links on the icons below the nav do not work. When I put the url (including the tag) into a new browser window it works ok) so I don't understand why it can't work from the icons (or even the text below the icons but it does from the main nav). Any ideas?

http://www.mapthemarket.co.uk

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please put relevant code here, so we can reproduce the issue without the need of external pages. This will also help you analyse the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any anchors in that page's source code. The links from the menu use some sort of Javascript for scrolling.

This is how you make an anchor in HTML:

```
<a href="#headhunting">Link to headhunting anchor</a>
<h3 id="headhunting">This is my headhunting section where the above link jumps to</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your scripts ([this one](http://www.mapthemarket.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/default.min.js?ver=4.0.1)), changes the behaviour of your links depending on the classes. The links at the top have the classes i.e. starting with `menu-item`, see below:

```
<div class="second"><div class="inner">
  <ul>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-1496" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home "><a href="http://www.mapthemarket.co.uk/#headhunting" class=""><i class="menu_icon fa blank"></i><span>Headhunting/Executive Search</span><span class="plus"></span></a></li>
 ...
```

To get the same behaviour, I suggest you copy the classes from the links at the top and put them on the links that are not working.Looks like you will also need to have the wrapper div with the class `second`.

Try adding some of your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so its easier for the community to help you.